# Is there way to improve a functional component using hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So I decided to give React Hooks a try. 
I have a component which contains a bunch of logics like form validation and form submission as shown below:

```
const MyAwesomeComponent: React.FC = ()=> {

   const [firstName, setFirstName]=useState('')
   const [lastName, setLastName]=useState('')
   const [formValidation, setFormValidation] = useState({
      firstName: true,
      lastName: true
   })

   const handleSubmitForm = (evt: React.FormEvent)=> {
      evt.preventDefault();
      handleSubmitButton()
   }

   const handleSubmitButton = ()=> {
      let formBody = {}

      if(!firstName) {
        setFormValidation({...formValidation, firstName: false})
      } else {
         formBody = {...formBody, {firstName}}
      }

      if(!lastName) {
        setFormValidation({...formValidation, lastName: false})
      } else {
         formBody = {...formBody, {lastName}}
      }

      // Nice proceed and submit the form to the backend
   }


   return (
      <form onSubmit={(evt)=>handleSubmitForm(evt)}>
        {/* form inputs go here */}
        <button onClick={()=>handleSubmitButton()}></button>
      </form>
   )
}

export default MyAwesomeComponent
```

The code above feels a bit bloated and a bit difficult to maintain in my opinion. Is there a way to improve the `handleSubmitButton` function in order to abstract some of its code into a separate function out of the `MyAwesomeComponent` component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For one thing, you could do

```
   const handleSubmitButton = ()=> {
      let formBody = {firstName, lastName}
      setFormValidation({firstName: !!firstName, lastName: !!lastName});

      // Nice proceed and submit the form to the backend
   }
```

In other words, why do it in two separate steps?  BTW if you haven't seen it, the `!!` is "not not" which converts a truthy or falsy value into an actual true or false.